# PHP: pipe and passthru to mix and match external linux program (with STDIN and STDOUT) as components

Tags: php

I am a PHP beginner. I want to invoke an external Unix command, pipe some stuff into it (e.g., string and files), and have the result appear in my output buffer (the browser).

Consider the following:

```
echo '<h1>stuff for my browser output window</h1>';
$fnmphp= '/tmp/someinputfile';
$sendtoprogram = "myheader: $fnmphp\n\n".get_file_contents($fnmphp);
popen2outputbuf("unixprogram < $sendtoprogram");
echo '<p>done</p>';
```

An even better solution would let PHP write myheader (into Unix program), then pipe the file `$fnmphp` (into Unix program); and the output of unixprogram would immediately go to my browser output buffer.

I don't think PHP uses `stdout`, so that my Unix program `STDOUT` output would make it into the browser.  Otherwise, this would happen to default if I used `system()`.  I can only think of solutions that require writing tempfiles.

I think I am standing on the line here (German idiom; wires crossed)--- this probably has an obvious solution.

update:

here is the entirely inelegant but pretty precise solution that I want to replace:

```
function pipe2eqb( $text ) {
        $whatever= '/tmp/whatever-'.time().'-'.$_SESSION['uid'];
        $inf = "$whatever.in";
        $outf= "$whatever.out";
        assert(!file_exists($inf));
        assert(!file_exists($outf));    
        file_put_contents($inf, $text);
        assert(file_exists($inf));
        system("unixprog < $inf > $outf");
        $fo= file_get_contents($outf);
        unlink($infilename);
        unlink($outfilename);
        return $fo;
}
```

It is easy to replace either the input or the output, but I want to replace both.  I will post a solution when I figure it out.

Comment: Do you want to display a file in the browser? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: It looks like you probably want `proc_open`, so that you can write your header to the `stdin` of the process, then read back the output and output it to the browser. The first example on the [proc_open man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) seems to be almost exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: the wording you choose: "pipe some stuff into it" - even you elaborate on it ("e.g., string and files") it's not clear what you mean as your example code does not contain any pipe. Also you should make clear why you don't thank that PHP uses `stdout`. Imagine it's the opposite and it actually uses standard input/output streams as it's common under *NIX systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best to do this is the proc_open family of functions

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin 
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout 
   2 => array("pipe", "w") // stderr
);
$cwd = NULL;//'/tmp';
$env = NULL;//array();
$cmd='unixprog ';
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);
assert(false!==$process);
```

now, to give arguments to unixprog, do like

```
$cmd='unixprog --arg1='.escapeshellarg($arg1).' --arg2='.escapeshellarg($arg2);
```

to talk to the program's stdin, do like

```
assert(strlen($stdinmessage)===fwrite($pipes[0],$stdinmessage));
```

to read from the process's stdout, do like

```
$stdout=file_get_contents($pipes[$1])
```

to read from the process's stderr, do like

```
$stderr=file_get_contents($pipes[$2])
```

to check if the program has finished, do like

```
$status=proc_get_status($process);
if($status['running']){echo 'child process is still running.';}
```

to check the return code of the process when it has finished,

```
echo 'return code from child process: '.$status['exitcode'];
```

to wait for the child process to finish, you CAN do

```
while(proc_get_status($process)['running']){sleep(1);}
```

this is a quick and easy way to do it, but it is not optimal. tl;dr: it may be slow or waste cpu. long version: 
 there is some nigh-optimal event-driven way to do this, but im not sure how to do it. imagine having to run a program 10 times, but the program execute in 100 milliseconds. this code would use 10 seconds! while optimal code would use only 1 second. you can use usleep() for microseconds, but its still not optimal, imagine if you're checking every 100 microseconds, but the program use 10 seconds to execute: you would waste cpu, checking the status 100,000 times, while optimal code would only check it once.. im sure there is a fancy way to let php sleep until the process finishes with some callback/signal, perhaps with stream_select , but i've yet to solve it. (if anybody have the solution, please let me know!)

-- read more at http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php